# React isn't rendering an array of objects with map() in a stateless component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, rendering

I've just started exploring React.js and I can't figure out why there are errors when I try to `map` over all of the days in the StudyDayList Component:

> 1) Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method
>   of `StudyDayList`.
>       in StudyDayList
>
> 2) Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `StudyDayList`.

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {StudyDayList} from '../src/components/StudyDayList';

window.React = React;

render(
<StudyDayList days={
    [
        {
            study: "React Essentials",
            date: new Date("4/7/2017"),                
            practice: true
        },
        {
            study: "Web Security",
            date: new Date("3/7/2017"),                
            practice: false
        }
    ]
} />, 
document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

### What I've tried

This particular part of the code doesn't work. All displays well if I am removing this part of the code in StudyDayList.js:

```
{days.map((day, i) => 
      <StudyDayRow key={i}                            
               study={day.study}
               date={day.date}
               practice={day.practice} />
)}
```

Also, I've tried to change syntaxis:

```
{days.map(day, i => (
      <StudyDayRow key={i}                    
               study={day.study}
               date={day.date}                                
               practice={day.practice} />
))}
```

and it gives another error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: day is not defined

I've checked the value of `days` from index.js by `propTypes` and `days: PropTypes.array` is `true` and the length is not null.

### StudyDayList Component

```
// StudyDayList.js

import Terrain from 'react-icons/lib/md/terrain';        
import StudyDayRow from './StudyDayRow';

export const StudyDayList = ({days}) => (
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Study</th>                
            <th>Practice</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>  

        // The part of code which I was removing 

        {days.map((day, i) => 
            <StudyDayRow key={i}                            
                        study={day.study}
                        date={day.date}
                        practice={day.practice} />
        )}    

    </tbody>        
</table>
)
```

### StudyDayRow Component

I'm not sure if StudyDayRow Component could cause the errors. I think it couldn't, but I've attached it in case it could.

```
// StudyDayRow.js

import Terrain from 'react-icons/lib/md/terrain';

export const StudyDayRow = ({study, date, practice}) => (
<tr>
    <td>
        {date.getMonth()+1}/{date.getDate()}/{date.getFullYear()}
    </td>
    <td>
        {study}
    </td>
    <td>
        {(practice) ? <Terrain /> : null}
    </td>
</tr>
)
```

Comment: are you sure Terrain is working as you expected?

Comment: Yes, it displayed properly with another component and I've just checked it by completely removing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine on [this CodeSandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/73PQ8oLG1). Your problem is likely arising from your `import` syntax, since you're doing `export const` and not `export default`. Note that you cannot do `export default const someVariable`, you'll need to export it after assigning the variable to a value.

If you want to keep your current syntax, change your imports to be named imports, like so

```
import { StudyDayRow } from './StudyDayRow';
```

Also, the reason `days.map(day, i => ...` doesn't work but `days.map((day, i) => ...` does is because arrow functions need the parenthesis whenever that function takes in more than one argument.

Comment: Thanks, it really didn't work because of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not exporting default `StudyDayRow`;

so, do something like that-

```
import {StudyDayRow} from './StudyDayRow';
```

or may edit-

```
export default const StudyDayRow = ({study, date, practice}) => (
....
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a syntax problem which I didn't notice.